# Multiple ListView and buttons widht

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, button

I'm trying to do [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60NV1.jpg) for an Android app, but I keep getting different results. My first problem is that I can only see the first ListView, while the second one is always hidden. The second one is that I'd like to create 3 buttons that have a "tab style". I tried using

```
android:layout_weight= "0.33"
```

for the buttons, but I still can't get that result.
This is my current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonP"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous"
    android:id="@+id/buttonP"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight= "0.33"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/buttonN"
    android:layout_above="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_weight= "0.33"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_list"
    android:id="@+id/custom_list_2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

And this is the layout for the elements of the lists

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/price"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/price"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: This layout. http://imgur.com/n9KelCt

Comment: There is one option to use ExpandableListview... Which will expland your list based on click, like the one from the menu bar. 
But you can use nestedRecyclerView which actually addressed lots of shortcomings of ListView...

Answer (score 0):

You should try accomplish your layout with this Percent Support Library:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent

It's really usefull when you need to create layouts based on percent width and height.
There are good tutorials on internet on how to use it effectively